# Is the IP address of a device the IP address of the router?

Tags: ip-address, router

I know that all devices connected to a router have the same public IP address

So does it mean that the public IP address of a device is also the IP address of the router?

Comment: Not necessary, it all depends on how you define "public IP address" (and also on how your ISP implements their infrastructure).

Comment: There are 2 kinds of IP addresses, right? A public IP address is used to access the internet. A private address is used to access the router's network. That is how I define "public IP address".

Comment: "A public IP address is used to access the internet." --- you may not have a public IP yet still be able to access internet. You may also be seen as different addresses depending on a lot of factors. If you really want an answer you need to be extremely precise in definitions.

Answer (score 1):

No, its not the same. Every device that connects to your internet network has a private IP address.

Therefore, your router generates private IP addresses that are unique identifiers for each device that differentiate them on the network.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Sorry for my unclear question. Not just devices, routers also have ip addresses, right? Every device in a router's network that accesses the internet has a different private IP address but the same public IP address. So my question really is if the public IP address of a device is the same as the IP address of the router.

Comment: "but the same public IP address" --- not necessary. "the public IP address of a device is the same as the IP address of the router" --- not necessary.

Comment: @TH __It is not the same__, because the device behind the router might use a VPN which will end up having a different public IP from the router.